# In Android WebView, how to return to previous page and reload the page to show updated page?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, reload

I am having trouble in Android WebView trying to return to the previous page and reload that previous page's URL to show the updated page.

I have tried using `myWebView.goBack()` followed by `myWebView.reload()`, but for some reason when I do that it just keeps loading the current page everytime I press the back button. My guess is that somehow `myWebView.reload()` is called before the WebView goes back to the previous page, hence it keeps reloading the current page's URL.

I have not been able to find an answer after lots of searching, but if anyone does in fact know of a page with an answer I would be grateful if you could link me to it.

This is what my code looks like where I tried to implement the `goBack()` and `reload()` methods.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
        myWebView.goBack();
        myWebView.reload();
    }
    else{
        if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce){
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
    }
}
```

The part with `doubleBackToExitPressedOnce` is used to get the user to press back twice before exiting the app if they can not go back to a previous page any further.